# How do I get Tweepy to not retrieve Tweets older than a week old?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm attempting to build a Twitter bot that retrieves #Fortnite tweets on Twitter, and then retweets them. The problem I'm encountering is Tweepy is retrieving tweets that are very old. Is it possible to make it so it won't retrieve tweets older than a week old?

I looked that the Twitter API docs, and found `since_id`, Is this what I need to implement?

```
import tweepy
import keys
import time, datetime

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.API_KEY, keys.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(keys.ACCESS_TOKEN, keys.SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def twitter_bot(hashtag, delay):
  while True:
    print(f"\n{datetime.datetime.now()}\n")

    for tweets in api.search_tweets(q=hashtag, result_type="recent", count=30):
      try:
        tweet_id = dict(tweets._json)["id"]
        tweet_text = dict(tweets._json)["text"]

        print("id: " + str(tweet_id))
        print("text: " + str(tweet_text))

        api.retweet(tweet_id)
        print("[+] Retweeted successfully!")

      except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
        print(e)

    time.sleep(delay)

twitter_bot("#Fortnite", 480)
```